# jquery event on dynamically generated elements without hard coding each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My problem is like so:

I have these listings that i generate using javascript in my HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="reveal-listing-id">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <div class="listing-header-container">
                        <div class="listing_header_section">15 Broad Steet <span class="blue-pips">|</span> Unit #number <span class="blue-pips">|</span> New York, NY</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row listing" id="listing-id">
                        <p class="subtleFont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy 
                            nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut 
                            wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
                            lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure 
                            dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
```

and javascript that on click will reveal the div that contains all the listing information which right now has id="listing-id". The java script looks like:

```
  $( "#reveal-listing-id" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ){
    $( "#listing-id" ).toggle( "blind", 600);
  });
```

Now i know for each HTML element i can easily place a unique ID and reveal ID when i run my javascript to build them but how can i make onClick events thats will reveal the corresponding DIV for the correct click without hard coding each one?

For example i would not want to do something like:

```
  $( "#reveal-listing-1" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ){
    $( "#listing-1" ).toggle( "blind", 600);
  });
  $( "#reveal-listing-2" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ){
    $( "#listing-2" ).toggle( "blind", 600);
  });
  $( "#reveal-listing-3" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ){
    $( "#listing-3" ).toggle( "blind", 600);
  });
  $( "#reveal-listing-4" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ){
    $( "#listing-4" ).toggle( "blind", 600);
  });
```

The number of listings can be anywhere from 5 to 500 so i would need a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- use a selector giving you all elements whose id starts with "reveal-listing-"
- compute the "#listing-x" id from the id of the clicked element

This would be like this :

```
 $('[id^="reveal-listing-"').on("click", function( event, ui ){
     $("#listing-"+this.id.slice(15)).toggle( "blind", 600);
 });
```

If you prefer to use event delegation to minimize the number of bindings, use

```
 $(document.body).on("click", '[id^="reveal-listing-"', function( event, ui ){
```

Comment: And since there can be up to 500 of them, event delegation wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have those divs "reveal-listing-id" being AJAX responses from pagination the future divs wont be binded to that jQuery function. That is because jQuery binds at the loading and wont rebind anything from the ajax response.

If you want a generic bind that works for every div and even for future divs you should do something like this:

```
<div id="list_container">
  <div class="row reveal-listing">
  </div>
  <div class="row reveal-listing">
  </div>
  <div class="row reveal-listing">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#list_container').on('click', '.reveal-listing', function() {
  $(this).find('#listing-id').toggle("blind", 600);
});
```

Note that I've created a div around yours so you only bind that not the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

Any control that is created after the event listener has been set will not be included in the control that will publish that event.

So if you want to do that you can either explicitly bind the event on the control at the time you create the control or you can create two functions in your code.

One will be the connect events function where you will look something like:

```
 function connectEvents(){
    $( "#reveal-listing-id" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ){
       $( "#listing-id" ).toggle( "blind", 600);
    });
 }
```

And another function to disconnect the events

```
function disconnectEvents(){
   $( "#reveal-listing-id" ).each(function(control){
      control.off('click');
   });
}
```

You then call the connectEvents function on document ready.

At the time you want to create another control dynamically, you will need to first call the disconnectEvents function so that all events from all controls are disconnected and the run your connectEvens function to reconnect all events for all controls (the new controls as well)

***All the controls that will be returned from the *$("#...")* query**